# A "prime number theorem" for simple groups

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

Our professor recently introduced us to simple groups. Since all groups of prime order are simple, I became interested in simple groups of composite order. Suppose I represent the number of simple groups less than $n$ by the function $f(n)$. An immediate conclusion is that eventually $\pi(n)<f(n)$. I am interested in the difference $f(n)-\pi(n)$. This will give me a way to estimate the number of composite simple groups less than $n$. I wanted to know if such an estimate exists or if there have been attempts at the same. For example, if this difference becomes constant or bounded then it tells us that composite simple groups are somehow "controlled" by the prime simple groups lying in their vicinity. On the other hand, if the difference is unbounded, I would like to find out if there is a way to find the rate at which the difference increases.

Comment: There are infinitely many simple groups not of prime order, so the difference is clearly not bounded.

Comment: I assume you are thinking in *finite* simple groups. Then you can 'count' them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups though I do not see the interest in it, since you know them all.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Do we have an asymptotic formula for $f(n)$ or the bound like we do for $\pi(n)$ ?

Comment: The ones of prime order will quickly dominate the rest, seeing as we only have a finite number of classes of others, and the orders of these grow very quickly.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Do there not exist arbitrarily large finite groups of composite order ? Could they not come from infinite groups ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by coming from infinite groups here.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft As subgroups of infinite groups.

Comment: Sure, they are all subgroups of suitable infinite groups. But I don't see how that is really relevant here.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Can we have arbitrarily large simple groups of composite order ?

Comment: Yes, as I said there are infinitely many not of prime order (and thus of composite order).

Comment: The orders of nonabelian finite simple groups are dominated by the groups ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ for a prime power $q$, which has order $q(q^2-1)/(q-1,2)$.

Comment: All prime order simple groups are finite cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups), the Classification of the Finite Simple Groups is one of the hallmarks of group theory. All of the simple groups of order less than $1000$ are of the form $PSL(2,q)$, where $q \in \{5, 7, 8, 9, 11\}$, the corresponding group orders are $60, 168, 504, 360$ and $660$. Every non-abelian group is either alternating $A_n$, for $n \geq 5$, a member of an infinite family (see above) parametrized by prime-powers and integers, or one of $26$ so-called *sporadic* simple groups. The largest one is called the Monster and has order $2^{46} · 3^{20} · 5^9 · 7^6 · 11^2 · 17 · 19 · 23 · 29 · 31 · 41 · 47 · 59 · 71
    = 808,017,424,794,512,875,886,459,904,961,710,757,005,754,368,000,000,000
    ≈ 8×10^{53}.$